# Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT driver installer cannot find GCC version number in /proc/version

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, compiling, gcc

I have learned a lot doing this and now I’m a bit hung up on this next part.

1. This is a 2009 15-inch MacBook Pro which has had internal components swapped out, such as a Samsung SSD and apparently 2 NVIDIA GeForce GPUs / graphics cards (a 9600M GT and a 9400M I believe).
2. I did a standard Ubuntu installation from a USB drive because Apple no longer supports OS updates on a Mac this old, so it was semi-unusable because without up to date browsers you can’t use many modern websites. I overwrote the entire disk with Ubuntu so there is no longer any Mac OS X on the disk at all.
3. It generally works, but there are some odd little bugs and performance issues. Sometimes after a certain sequence of actions the screen gets stuck in a weird way where it won’t open application windows anymore even though it says the application is open. Sometimes it gets frozen and you have to reboot.
4. I did some system tests and my working assumptions is that the computer is too hot, the battery is old, and it has proprietary graphics cards inside that Ubuntu doesn’t know how to handle by default.
5. I’m planning on cleaning the fan with compressed air and reapplying thermal paste, and replacing the battery, but today I wondered if the performance issues would be mainly linked to something on the software level, so I decided to try to install the Nvidia drivers. I ran some commands and saw my Ubuntu is using the Nouveau driver by default, I think.
6. It may have been possible to install additional drivers from the Software and Updates application under Additional Drivers, but when I go there, nothing shows up like an additional Nvidia graphics driver detected for installation.
7. So I went to the Nvidia site to download the driver manually. I did find the exact driver for GeForce 9600M GT. It downloaded with the same name as GeForce 9600 GT, so I’m wondering if there is one single driver installer that works for both the mobile and desktop versions of the graphics card.
8. I ran the installer a few times and got various issues that I addressed one by one. I can’t have an X server running while it’s installing, so I changed a certain part of a file from `splash` to `splash 3` and did `grub-update`, then rebooted, to boot into a tty with `gdm` not launched. It asked me if I wanted to use DKMS, first I said yes, but there was some error so then I tried “no”; that seemed to get me further in the installation. I also had to disable Nouveau to get through the installer.
9. The hang-up now is it gives me an error that it cannot find the gcc version number in the `/proc/version` string. I have looked at it myself and I can clearly see `gcc-12` at one part of the string. The installer gives me the option to proceed without worrying about the gcc version check, or to abort and edit the file to include the gcc version.

I tried to do it without the gcc version check but the build failed. I have checked and am pretty sure I have plenty of functioning gcc versions installed - 11, 12.

I assume my gcc itself works perfectly fine. I assume my /proc/version string is probably also fine.

My best guess might be, the installer itself is having some issue? Does it have anything to do with this being an older computer?

The graphics cards aren’t even listed as “legacy” on the Nvidia site, so I wouldn’t think the installer is like deprecated.

Why can’t it see the GCC version number? And even if it can’t, why can’t it still invoke GCC normally and use it successfully in the build? This is a fresh Ubuntu installation, my GCC should be just fine.

Comment: too new gcc for that old(?!) driver?